# tween.js rotation starts from beginning each turn instead of rotating for additional degrees

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I have chained 4 different `tweens` to create a loop, and one of the `tweens` that i want to happen is when loaded `gltf` model reaches certain y: position i want it to rotate for **additional** 90 degrees. But currently it just rotates from 0 to 90 degrees everytime it reaches that certain y: position.

```js
...
  var currentRotation = 0;
  const tweenRotation = new TWEEN.Tween({ z: currentRotation })
    .to({ z: currentRotation + MathUtils.degToRad(90) }, 2000) // 2s linear tween for rotating 90dg
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
    .onUpdate((rotationFunc) => {
      model.rotation.z = rotationFunc.z;
      currentRotation += MathUtils.degToRad(90);
    })
    .onComplete(() => {
      currentRotation += MathUtils.degToRad(90);
    });
...
```

I also tried storing the initial rotation value as a

```js
var currentRotation = model.rotation.z;
```

but it did not work, however when i console.info inside `.onUpdate` for current rotation it seems like its adding up value each time as expected but keeps teleporting the 0 degree to rotate for 90 degrees everytime. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by delaying the start of chained 2nd tween after first tween gets finished. In that specific time window, rotation happens.

I also changed the way I wrote for the rotation, now it is in a function. I can now change the degree parameter and just execute the function to add certain degrees each lap as i want.

```js
tween1.onComplete(() => {
    rotateModel(90);
  }); // after tween1 gets finished rotation happens immediately

  let currentRotation = model.rotation.z;

  function rotateModel(degrees) {
    var targetRotation = currentRotation + MathUtils.degToRad(degrees);
    var tweenRotation = new TWEEN.Tween({ z: currentRotation })
      .to({ z: targetRotation }, 2000)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
      .onUpdate((rotationFunc) => {
        model.rotation.z = rotationFunc.z;
      })
      .onComplete(() => {
        currentRotation += degrees;
      });

    tweenRotation.start();
  }

  const tween12 = new TWEEN.Tween(model.position)
    .to({ y: 0 }, 1000)
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Circular.InOut)
    .onUpdate((coords) => {
      model.position.y = coords.y;
    });
  tween12.delay(2200); // delayed the start of 2nd tween so it'll rotate in the meantime
```